# VirtualBox reports corrupt installation image

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, amd-ryzen

I can't make VirtualBox work on a new company laptop (ThinkPad T495, AMD 3500U PRO).

Host: W10 Enterprise 1909.

Guest: CentOS, Xubuntu (20.04, 18.04), Debian

Under VB 5.2, 6.0 I can't finish any setup. It usually ends with an error about corrupt installation image.
VB 6.1.6 completes installation, but crashes right after or during next VM reboot.
Of course all downloaded images passed checksums.

I've never seen anything like this with any VB+distro combination. All scenarios above work perfectly fine on my private PC (W10 Pro 1909, Intel).

I know AMD doesn't support nested virtualization, but plain VB should work.
All settings in BIOS and Windows Functions were correct.

Any guess?

WSL works fine (of course with Hyper-V etc turned on).